# Onkey function in Python Turtle not working for my input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Previously in my program, I used inputs in the console for the player to enter guesses but now I want to use the `onkey()` function in Python 3.6.1 Turtle. I want it to detect if the player presses any key and then make a string saying something like "guess='a'". I want something like this:

```
import turtle

canvas=turtle.Screen()
t=turtle.Pen()
guess=0

def a():
    guess='a'

canvas.onkey(a,'a')
canvas.listen()
```

Obviously another defined function for each letter of the alphabet.
However after this, when pressing 'a' and putting 'print(guess)', it is not printing 'a'.

Comment: You question has too much irrelevant code. On the other hand, it is incomplete. What is `canvas`? How did you define it? Please post an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have changed the post. Sorry for incovieniece

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you forgot a `global` statement in the `a()` function so it's reference to `guess` was local, not global.  Here's an example implementation:

```
import turtle

def a():
    global guess
    guess += 'a'

def b():
    global guess
    guess += 'b'

def question():
    print(guess)

guess = ''

canvas = turtle.Screen()

canvas.onkey(a, 'a')
canvas.onkey(b, 'b')
canvas.onkey(question, '?')

canvas.listen()

canvas.mainloop()
```

You can type 'a' and 'b' as much as you want -- when you type '?' the string of letters you've built up will get printed.